# New-SSHSession found in module Posh-ssh but could not be loaded in powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh, posh-ssh

I want to create an ssh session using PowerShell that's why I have used the Posh-SSh module but after importing Posh-SSH, the New-SSHSession function is not loaded.

Code:

```
Import-Module -Name Posh-SSH
$targetServer=''
$UserName=''
$PassWord=''
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $PassWord -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Managemen.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName,$pass
     try
          {
           $session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $targetServer -Port "22" -Credential $cred -AcceptKey -Force -Verbose
            $result = Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $session -Command "hostname"
            Write-Host "OpenFirstSshConnection says: $($result.Output)"
          }

            catch
        {
            Write-Error "Exception in first ssh connection (session details: $session): $_"
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
            throw
        }
```

Error: The New-SSHSession found in the module but could not be loaded. For more info run Import-Module Posh-SSH.

Comment: Why not using the built-in OpenSSH client? Just execute `ssh`. No need for external third party stuff. `ssh` is available since feature update 1809.

Comment: New-SSHSession should use ssh per default, when available.

Comment: Need to connect on a remote server which is present on another machine